# Mod Rewrite with Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

Basically I have a joomla instance with an article that uses URL rewriting.

http://example.com/kids-and-family/185-summer-camp.html goes to the corresponding article when typed into the url.

I now want this URL to be accessed by using http://example.com/camp

This seems to be the bulk of the .htaccess file:

```
########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

How do I make this a reality using the .htaccess? Or can someone provide me with a good example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried linking directly to the article using an Articles/Article Layout menu item? You should then be able to specify `camp` in the `Alias` field to get your link.